# ForeignKeyAutocompleteAdmin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-extensions

Given these two models:

```
class Product(Model):
    upc = CharField(max_length=96, unique=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'scrapers'

class Order(Model):
    ...
    product = ForeignKey('scrapers.Product', related_name='orders', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = OrderManager()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'scrapers'
```

And this admin.py:

```
class OrderAdmin(ForeignKeyAutocompleteAdmin):
    related_search_fields = {
        'product': ('upc', 'retailer_offerings__name')
    }
    fields = ('product', 'client', 'completed', 'expires', 'amount', 'filled')


admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

Having done collectstatic and declared django_extensions and my app in INSTALLED_APPS. Why am I getting this:

```
[04/Dec/2016 05:54:28] "GET /admin/scrapers/product/foreignkey_autocomplete/?search_fields=upc&app_label=scrapers&model_name=product&q=045496 HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Not Found: /admin/scrapers/product/foreignkey_autocomplete/change/
[04/Dec/2016 05:54:28] "GET /admin/scrapers/product/foreignkey_autocomplete/change/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1875
```

On input to the input field (box to the left not pk input to the right)?

The Product table has millions of rows and the default admin configuration doesn't handle this well so I tried the extensions package solution. The widget is requesting `product/foreignkey_autocomplete` but a quick grep through manage.py show_urls shows that only /orders has been registered with the foreignkeyautocomplete package. I don't see anything in the docs addressing url configuration (I assume this is done when registering with the admin). How can I get this to work?

Partial solution:

after examining the urls and realizing it was attempting top send the search queries to /product/foreignkey_autocomplete/... I tried to create an empty admin for that model as well. It worked but the behavior is still odd. It seems to stop searching after 4-5 characters have been entered and doesn't bother refreshing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per my update, adding a `ForeignKeyAutocompleteAdmin` for the other side of the relation created the missing urls and the functionality seems to work

Comment: Thanks, @Verbal_Kint. This is maddening. Why isn't it in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

@Verbal_Kint I think I may have figured the same issue as yours.

I have a InlineModelAdmin "TaskInline" for model *Task*, a field "SCRIPT" of it is a foreign-key to model *TestScript* (managed by "TestAdmin").

After I made sure the related model's ModelAdmin (here for me it's TestAdmin) inherits ForeignKeyAutoCompleteAdmin instead of admin.ModelAdmin, then made sure TestAdmin had an method wrap as below:

```
class TestAdmin(ForeignKeyAutocompleteAdmin):

    ForeignKeyAutocompleteAdmin.model = TestScript

    def wrap(self, view):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapper.model_admin = self
        return update_wrapper(wrapper, view)

    def get_urls(self):
        info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name

        urlpatterns = super(TestAdmin, self).get_urls()
        urlpatterns.insert(0, url(r'^(.+)/run/', self.wrap(self.run_view), name='%s_%s_run' % info))
        urlpatterns.insert(0, url(r'^add/$', self.wrap(self.add_view), name='%s_%s_add' % info))
        urlpatterns.insert(0, url(r'^add_to_template_mission/$', self.wrap(self.add_to_template_mission_view), name='%s_%s_add_to_template_mission' % info))
        urlpatterns.insert(0, url(r'^add_to_mission/$', self.wrap(self.add_to_mission_view), name='%s_%s_add_to_mission' % info))
        urlpatterns.insert(0, url(r'^$', self.wrap(self.changelist_view), name='%s_%s_changelist' % info))

        return urlpatterns

class TaskInline(ForeignKeyAutocompleteTabularInline):

    model = Task

    related_search_fields = {
        'SCRIPT': ('FILENAME', 'FILE_PATH', 'FILE_CONTENT', ),
    }
```

And, don't forget to have

```
urlpatterns = super(TestAdmin, self).get_urls()
```

in `get_urls()` inside `TestAdmin`

Then, everything got working fine.

Maybe there is a better way, but this did solve my problem. Hope this can help.